# Are there any resources that I can use to convert a Python program to an .exe using my own edited versions of installed packages?

Tags: python

In a program I'm creating, I had to go into some of my downloaded libraries and alter some of the code, and now I am attempting to convert the program. However, Auto py to exe just attempts to download the packages on it's own when converting my program. Are there any resources I can use to convert 100% of my raw program?